# Opening project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I've googled for the answer and read many forums and stackoverflow threads but I still can't get it to work.

I just started trying to develop my first Android app, and after following the instructions listed on the website, when I started the project, it opened with two tabs, one showing a java file, and the other showing an xml file. The tab with the xml file also had this simulation of an android phone on it where I could play around with the GUI.

When I stopped working on it, I closed all the tabs and closed eclipse, but now I want to work on it again and I don't know how to get it back to the setup showing the java and the xml file with the little simulation. I don't even know where the activity_main.xml is located.

I don't want to create a brand new project.

I tried importing a project, but the finish button is always grayed out or it wont let me import because it says that a project already exists in the workspace, or after I click on the folder containing all the bin, res, src, etc. files, and I click OK to import it, nothing happens.

Is it possible to just click on a single file, like the .sln file in visual studio, that will automatically launch eclipse with your project ready to go?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: windows 8.1 running classicshell

Answer (score 1):

The activity_main.xml is located in your_project/res/layout.
Just open Eclipse and navigate to this directory in Package Explorer window:

[image: Package Explorer]
When you double click the activity_main.xml you should see the XML and Graphical Layout tabs at the bottom.

Here is a description of android project structure:
http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#ApplicationModules

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to reopen your project again:

1. Try to open the project explorer:
   -> Window -> View -> Project Explorer -> Hit refresh
2. Open your .project file (in your workspace) an edit the name in the xml name tag and try do import again.

Please make a backup before.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you uncheck the copy attribute when you import the project, this solve the `project is already exit` problem, and you can try both `Existing Project Into Workspace` and `Existing Android Code Into Workspace`.
2. The layout file lay in  project_name/res/layout.
3. Source file lay in project_name/src.

You can double click to open your files, and your files remain open the next time you open eclipse, only if you don't close them when you exit the eclipse.